# Can a long road trip cause a loss of engine coolant?

Tags: engine, coolant, coolant-leak

I went on a long road trip not long ago and just recently my car told me to check the coolant level. I checked the level and it was low, however I can't find any signs of a leak. Could the level be low because of the long trip?

Answer (score 1):

The coolant is for the most part, a sealed system. If the system is running correctly you shouldn't lose any coolant over time or on long road trips. There will be a reason why it's missing, but it may not be obvious. My suggestion is to fill it back up to full and keep an eye on it. Unless you find a leak or a reason, there isn't much you can do about it but refill.

Answer (score 1):

You can lose some coolant over time, but typically not just from a long trip. What we don't know is what the level was before your trip and how long it had been since any coolant was added. So, that makes everything we say simply guesses.

Evaporation from the expansion tank is usually why you add coolant. Most vehicles with coolant level sensors monitor the expansion tank, not the actual level inside the engine. This is to let you know when to top it up, rather than waiting until the engine is about to overheat.

Since you said there are no external leaks, another reason you may be losing coolant could be internal engine leaks. As Paulster2 suggested, monitoring how frequent you need to add coolant will give you an idea about what is going on. If you are getting the notification to add coolant frequently, you may want to have the car serviced.

If this was the first time you have had to add coolant, things are most likely just fine.